# How can I read from a Perl filehandle that is an array element?

Tags: perl, arrays, filehandle

I quickly jotted off a Perl script that would average a few files with just columns of numbers.  It involves reading from an array of filehandles.  Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Symbol;

die "Usage: $0 file1 [file2 ...]\n" unless scalar(@ARGV);

my @fhs;

foreach(@ARGV){
    my $fh = gensym;
    open $fh, $_ or die "Unable to open \"$_\"";
    push(@fhs, $fh);
}

while (scalar(@fhs)){
    my ($result, $n, $a, $i) = (0,0,0,0);
    while ($i <= $#fhs){
        if ($a = <$fhs[$i]>){
            $result += $a;
            $n++;
            $i++;
        }
        else{
            $fhs[$i]->close;
            splice(@fhs,$i,1);
        }
    }
    if ($n){ print $result/$n . "\n"; }
}
```

This doesn't work.  If I debug the script, after I initialize @fhs it looks like this:

```
  DB<1> x @fhs
0  GLOB(0x10443d80)
   -> *Symbol::GEN0
         FileHandle({*Symbol::GEN0}) => fileno(6)
1  GLOB(0x10443e60)
   -> *Symbol::GEN1
         FileHandle({*Symbol::GEN1}) => fileno(7)
```

So far, so good.  But it fails at the part where I try to read from the file:

```
  DB<3> x $fhs[$i]
0  GLOB(0x10443d80)
   -> *Symbol::GEN0
         FileHandle({*Symbol::GEN0}) => fileno(6)
  DB<4> x $a
0  'GLOB(0x10443d80)'
```

$a is filled with this string rather than something read from the glob.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: I will gift you 1000 rep for stopping using P...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only use a simple scalar variable inside `<>` to read from a filehandle.  `<$foo>` works.  `<$foo[0]>` does not read from a filehandle; it's actually equivalent to `glob($foo[0])`.  You'll have to use the `readline` builtin, a temporary variable, or use [IO::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::File) and OO notation.

```
$text = readline($foo[0]);
# or
my $fh = $foo[0];  $text = <$fh>;
# or
$text = $foo[0]->getline;  # If using IO::File
```

If you weren't deleting elements from the array inside the loop, you could easily use a temporary variable by changing your `while` loop to a `foreach` loop.

Personally, I think using `gensym` to create filehandles is an ugly hack.  You should either use IO::File, or pass an undefined variable to `open` (which requires at least Perl 5.6.0, but that's almost 10 years old now).  (Just say `my $fh;` instead of `my $fh = gensym;`, and Perl will automatically create a new filehandle and store it in `$fh` when you call `open`.)

Comment: Or the equivalent to `<HANDLE>`, which is spelled out as `readline HANDLE`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use a bit of magic, you can do this very simply:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 file1 [file2 ...]\n" unless @ARGV;

my $sum   = 0;

# The current filehandle is aliased to ARGV
while (<>) {
    $sum += $_;
} 
continue {
    # We have finished a file:
    if( eof ARGV ) {
        # $. is the current line number.
        print $sum/$. , "\n" if $.;
        $sum = 0;

        # Closing ARGV resets $. because ARGV is 
        # implicitly reopened for the next file.
        close ARGV;  
    }
}
```

Unless you are using a very old perl, the messing about with `gensym` is not necessary.  IIRC, perl 5.6 and newer are happy with normal lexical handles: `open my $fh, '<', 'foo';`

Comment: I like.  But what's `$count` for?

Comment: Also, `unless` will implicitly use `@ARGV` in scalar context... and I wouldn't count this as magic, this is how I'd write it too :)

Comment: Good points.  The `unless scalar` is left over from pasting the OP's code.  The $count was left over from before I realized I could use the line number.

Answer (score 1):

I have trouble understanding your logic. Do you want to read several files, which just contains numbers (one number per line) and print its average?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @fh;
foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
    open(my $fh, '<', $f) or die "Cannot open $f: $!";
    push @fh, $fh;
}

foreach my $fh (@fh) {
    my ($sum, $n) = (0, 0);
    while (<$fh>) {
        $sum += $_;
        $n++;
    }
    print "$sum / $n: ", $sum / $n, "\n" if $n;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the files are not guaranteed to have the same number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a `for` loop would work better for you, where you could actually use the standard read (iteration) operator.

```
for my $fh ( @fhs ) { 
    while ( defined( my $line = <$fh> )) {
        # since we're reading integers we test for *defined*
        # so we don't close the file on '0'
        #...
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

It doesn't look like you want to shortcut the loop at all. Therefore, `while` seems to be the wrong loop idiom.